# How to implement unknown/optional fields in SQLAlchemy, where the user can add their own new fields?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am writing a python program also using Sqlalchemy, which stores an entry for something, but I would like to let the user add their own fields.

Here's my model at the moment, using Python 3 and Sqlalchemy

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('folders.id'),     nullable=True)
    name = Column(String(128))
    key = Column(String(256))
    value = Column(String(512))
    extras = Column(Binary)
    next_scheduled = Column(DateTime)
    new = Column(Integer)
```

How should I go about functionality for the user adding their own fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

Create two new tables, one for fields and one for answers.  Make the answer a child of both the question (user-defined field) and original item.  Users can add fields by adding lines to the fields table, and you can retrieve the answers to all custom fields whenever you pull the original item:

```
class CustomField(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'custom_fields'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(128)) # internal name in this case
    title = Column(Text) # Text of field label

class CustomResponse(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'custom_responses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.id'))
    item = relationship('Item', backref='custom_responses')
    custom_field_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('custom_fields.id'))
    custom_field = relationship('CustomField') # put backref here if needed
    value = Column(Text) # Actual answer
```

You can even provide instructions to whatever you're using to draw the form by putting a `widget = Column(...)` column on your custom_fields table, or any other options/instructions.  If you want to have each custom field available to only one item, then duplicate the `item_id` column and `item` relationship on the CustomField model.

No sense in trying to force all the data on one row; let sqlalchemy take care of relationships.  In this case, you could get all custom field questions and answers through the relationships:

If `i = Item()`, then `i.custom_responses` will return a list of all completed CustomResponse objects associated with that item, and for each `custom_response`, you can get the question with `custom_response.custom_field`.